# HU and Zernike Moments for Gesture Recognition

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, computer-vision, gesture-recognition

I am working on gesture recognition using HU-Moments and Zerkine moments. I have already calculate HU-Moments but i can't get the results. The results are ;

> HU-Moments : 0, 0.0526892508239683, 0, 0, 0, 0

for the image attached here with. I have referenced at:[Wikipedia Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment). If code is necessary i will provide it later, but my question is,are the moments i am calculating for the image is correct? I will necessarily ask if anyone shares the computational complexity of `Zernike-Moments`. My next step is to calculate `Zernike-Moments` but what i have found was [this](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/SHUTLER3/node11.html). Can I proceed with this?

[image: Edge Detected Image of hand Gesture]

Comment: I don't have an answer to this and frankly I have no idea either. Though I would love to see some update on this. :) I am happy I joined SO.

Comment: Assuming that `HU-Moments : 0, 0.0526892508239683, 0, 0, 0, 0` corresponds to the Hu invariant moments I1 through I6, your results do not appear to be correct. Can you post your code and your intermediate results?

Comment: Also, Hu moments are meant to be invariant to rotation, translation and scaling. Did you try rotating/translating/scaling your image and verifying that you got the same results?

Comment: @beaker: I have now corrected my code, now the result appears correct. And for Zernike moments, it is not necessary to compute both HU-Moments and Zernike moments, so i choose HU-Moments as it is translation, rotation and scale in variant, i have verified italready.Still need to post code?

Comment: But the mystery continues again. How the testing and training will be done, for real time interaction using SVM library?

Comment: @TNC: If you've got the correct results there's no need to post your code. For training the classifier you should probably post a follow-up question to [tag:machine-learning].

Comment: I came with the conclusion: For 'HU-Moments', calculation are needed from dilated and eroded image.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I am sorry this topic is related with C# :(

You can use this OpenCV and python implementation below:

```
import cv2
def hu_moments(image):
    image = rgb2gray(image)
    feature = cv2.HuMoments(cv2.moments(image)).flatten()
    return feature

lenx = x_train.shape[0] # Your Inputs!
x_train_HU = np.zeros((lenx, 7))

for NUM in range(lenx):
  x_train_HU[NUM] = hu_moments(x_train[NUM]) # Your Inputs!

lenx = x_test.shape[0]
x_test_HU = np.zeros((lenx, 7))

for NUM in range(lenx):
  x_test_HU[NUM] = hu_moments(x_test[NUM]) # Your Inputs!
```